# Failed to compile test.tex after successful TinyTeX installation via tinytex

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

I am trying to install TinyTeX via the convenient [tinytex-package for R](https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/).

After having had a few issues with getting the installation to run smoothly on MacOS, the `install_tinytex()` function now executes properly and ends with the statement:

> TinyTeX installed to /Users/X/Library/TinyTeX

However, when trying to execute `pdflatex('test.tex')` to test the installation, the console instead returns:

> Error: Failed to compile test.tex

Apparently the installation did not execute properly. Am I missing something or isn't this supposed to work after a successful TinyTeX installation via tinytex?

The `texput.log` displays the following error message:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.11.2)  2 NOV 2018 14:47
>   entering extended mode
>    restricted \write18 enabled.
>    %&-line parsing enabled.
>   **test.tex
>   ! Emergency stop.
>   <*> test.tex
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  3 strings out of 494585
>   99 string characters out of 6174649  51539 words of memory out of
>   5000000  3743 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  3640
>   words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  14
>   hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out
>   of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Do you get more error messages than just the failure notice? Are there any error messages in `test.log` if the file exists?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include further information such as error messages.

Comment: thank you for the input, I updated the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted error message indicates that there is no file `test.tex` in your current working directory. Either create a sample LaTeX file or use an existing file. If you do not have any LaTeX file available, you can try

```
pdflatex('sample2e.tex')
```

This will translate `smaple2e.tex`, which should be part of every LaTeX distribution.